# if statements in PHP mapping json entries to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to map JSON files into a mysql database I want based on the value of a particular element in JSON to if it is equal to that value put the entries in the database but when I run my application it returns everything

php for table 1 which is supposed to check if resource type is equal to instance put entries into table :

```
<?php 


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json_map");
$response = array(); 
$res=array();
$result='' ;
foreach(glob('C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\awsconfig\app\views\*.json') as $filename)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($filename);

    if($json!=null)
    { 
        $decoded=json_decode($json,true); 
        //$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
        //$ss=$decode["array"]; 
        //echo $decoded['number']; 

        if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
        { 
            foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
            {
                //for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 

                $cfi=$configurationItems;
                if(isset($cfi["resourceType"]["AWS::EC2::Instance"]));

                if(isset($cfi["configurationItemVersion"]) && isset($cfi["configurationItemCaptureTime"])  && isset($cfi["configurationStateId"])&& isset($cfi["awsAccountId"]) && isset($cfi["awsAccountId"]) )
                {
                        $configurationItemVersion=$configurationItems["configurationItemVersion"]; 
                          echo "<br />","configuration_Item_Version:",$configurationItemVersion,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationItemCaptureTime=$configurationItems["configurationItemCaptureTime"]; 
                          echo "configurationItemCaptureTime:",$configurationItemCaptureTime,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationStateId=$configurationItems["configurationStateId"]; 
                          echo "configurationStateId:",$configurationStateId,"<br />"; 
                        $awsAccountId=$configurationItems["awsAccountId"]; 
                          echo "awsAccountId:",$awsAccountId,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationItemStatus=$configurationItems["configurationItemStatus"]; 
                          echo "configurationItemStatus:",$configurationItemStatus,"<br />"; 
                        $resourceId=$configurationItems["resourceId"]; 
                          echo "resourceId:",$resourceId,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationStateMd5Hash=$configurationItems["configurationStateMd5Hash"]; 
                          echo "configurationStateMd5Hash:",$configurationStateMd5Hash,"<br />"; 
                        $resourceType=$configurationItems["resourceType"]; 
                          echo "resourceType:",$resourceType,"<br />";   
                        $ARN= isset($cfi["ARN"]) ? $cfi["ARN"] : ''; 
                          echo "ARN:",$ARN,"<br />";
                        $awsRegion= isset($cfi["awsRegion"]) ? $cfi["awsRegion"] : ''; 
                          echo "awsRegion:",$awsRegion,"<br />";  
                        $availabilityZone= isset($cfi["availabilityZone"]) ? $cfi["availabilityZone"] : ''; 
                          echo "availabilityZone:",$availabilityZone,"<br />";
                        $resourceCreationTime= isset($cfi["resourceCreationTime"]) ? $cfi["resourceCreationTime"] : ''; 
                          echo "resourceCreationTime:",$resourceCreationTime,"<br />";



                       $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO     configuration_item(configuration_item_version,configuration_item_capture_time,configuration_state_id, aws_account_id, configuration_item_status, resource_id, arn, aws_region, availability_zone,configuration_state_md5_hash, resource_type, resource_creation_time)

                       VALUES('$configurationItemVersion','$configurationItemCaptureTime','$configurationStateId','$awsAccountId','$configurationItemStatus','$resourceId','$ARN','$awsRegion','$availabilityZone','$configurationStateMd5Hash','$resourceType','$resourceCreationTime' )")or die("Insert Failed ".((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));; 

    }


                    // check if row inserted or not 
                    if ($result)
                    { 
                        // successfully inserted into database 
                        $response["code"] = 1; 
                        $response["message"] = "successfully updated configuration items "; 

                        // echoing JSON response 
                        echo json_encode($response); 
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        echo mysql_error();
                        // failed to insert row 
                        $response["code"] = 2; 
                        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 

                        // echoing JSON response 
                        echo json_encode($response); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
```

?>

php for table two which is supposed to do as above but where equal to volume into a different table :

```
<?php 


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json_map");
$response = array(); 
$res=array();
$result='' ;
foreach(glob('C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\awsconfig\app\views\*.json') as $filename)
{
    $json = file_get_contents($filename);

    if($json!=null)
    { 
        $decoded=json_decode($json,true); 
        //$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
        //$ss=$decode["array"]; 
        //echo $decoded['number']; 

        if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
        { 
            foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
            {
                //for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 

                $cfi=$configurationItems;


                if(isset($cfi["resourceType"]["AWS::EC2::Volume"]));

                {
                        $configurationItemVersion=$cfi["configurationItemVersion"]; 
                          echo "<br />","configuration_Item_Version:",$configurationItemVersion,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationItemCaptureTime=$cfi["configurationItemCaptureTime"]; 
                          echo "configurationItemCaptureTime:",$configurationItemCaptureTime,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationStateId=$cfi["configurationStateId"]; 
                          echo "configurationStateId:",$configurationStateId,"<br />"; 
                        $awsAccountId=$cfi["awsAccountId"]; 
                          echo "awsAccountId:",$awsAccountId,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationItemStatus=$cfi["configurationItemStatus"]; 
                          echo "configurationItemStatus:",$configurationItemStatus,"<br />"; 
                        $resourceId=$cfi["resourceId"]; 
                          echo "resourceId:",$resourceId,"<br />"; 
                        $configurationStateMd5Hash=$cfi["configurationStateMd5Hash"]; 
                          echo "configurationStateMd5Hash:",$configurationStateMd5Hash,"<br />"; 
                        $resourceType=$cfi["resourceType"]; 
                          echo "resourceType:",$resourceType,"<br />";   
                        $ARN= isset($cfi["ARN"]) ? $cfi["ARN"] : ''; 
                          echo "ARN:",$ARN,"<br />";
                        $awsRegion= isset($cfi["awsRegion"]) ? $cfi["awsRegion"] : ''; 
                          echo "awsRegion:",$awsRegion,"<br />";  
                        $availabilityZone= isset($cfi["availabilityZone"]) ? $cfi["availabilityZone"] : ''; 
                          echo "availabilityZone:",$availabilityZone,"<br />";
                        $resourceCreationTime= isset($cfi["resourceCreationTime"]) ? $cfi["resourceCreationTime"] : ''; 
                          echo "resourceCreationTime:",$resourceCreationTime,"<br />";

                        {



    }




                       $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO     cfi_vol(configuration_item_version,configuration_item_capture_time,configuration_state_id, aws_account_id, configuration_item_status, resource_id, arn, aws_region, availability_zone,configuration_state_md5_hash, resource_type, resource_creation_time)

                       VALUES('$configurationItemVersion','$configurationItemCaptureTime','$configurationStateId','$awsAccountId','$configurationItemStatus','$resourceId','$ARN','$awsRegion','$availabilityZone','$configurationStateMd5Hash','$resourceType','$resourceCreationTime' )")or die("Insert Failed ".((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));; 





                    // check if row inserted or not 
                    if ($result)
                    { 
                        // successfully inserted into database 
                        $response["code"] = 1; 
                        $response["message"] = "successfully updated configuration items volume"; 

                        // echoing JSON response 
                        echo json_encode($response); 
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        echo mysql_error();
                        // failed to insert row 
                        $response["code"] = 2; 
                        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 

                        // echoing JSON response 
                        echo json_encode($response); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

unfortunately when I run this I get everything returned

Comment: can you share some snippet from json file.

Comment: why you put semicolon at the end of if statement that's error

Comment: ` I get everything returned` - what does it mean? first part inserts how many records? records are different? second part inserts records? what does it mean ` I get everything returned`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove semicolon after if statement

```
   if(isset($cfi["resourceType"]["AWS::EC2::Volume"]))
```

Also check below line.

```
   if(isset($cfi["resourceType"]["AWS::EC2::Instance"]));
```